# The problem of not displaying the <fragment> option in the Android Studio palette

Tags: android

When I want to use the Fragment option in the Android Studio palette, I don't find this option.

But when I see other people's Android [This is an image of my Android Studio palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9womJ.jpg)Studio environment on the Internet or other places, this option is available for them in the palette, and from this point of view, they have no problem.

Has anyone encountered this problem and been able to solve it?

Before asking this question, I updated Android Studio but my problem was not solved.

Comment: Do you mean "fragmentContainerView"? https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView